# String is entered twice in a text box

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a bit of a strange issue that happens about 50% of the time when I run my selenium.

What tends to happen when I run the script is the following:

- Firefox browser opens
- "Leeds Bradford" is entered in the textbox
- Firefox windows maximises
- "Leeds Bradford" is then entered again next to the original Leeds Bradford on the same text box

This causes the script to not able to continue and error out as it cannot find "Leeds Bradford" as the text box states "LeedsBradfordLeeds Bradford". There is nothing in the code that states to enter it twice, so I was wondering why this could be? Is it possible it can be a cookie issue where the browser manages to store existing form data just for that text box before realizing my script is kicking in?

If so then is there a way to clear the cookies? Or maybe better clear the text box before typing "Leeds Bradford" so that it will always ensure it's entering "Leeds Bradford" in a clear text box?

Code is below:

```
# Search Flights
FROM = "Leeds Bradford"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.jet2.com")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

# wait for the page to load
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "departure-airport-input")))

# fill out the form
return_flight = driver.find_element_by_id('return-flight-selector').click()

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input").send_keys(FROM)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ui-id-1 .ui-menu-item"))).click()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you say try to clear input field before entering value:

```
depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input")
depart_from.clear()
depart_from.send_keys(FROM)
```